# [[maybe_unused]] applied to static data members

Tags: c++, c++17

The draft standard states about [[maybe_unused]] in 10.6.6 item 2

"The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a variable, a non-static data member, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator."

Is there any reason to exclude static data members from this? i.e.

```
struct Foo {
    [[maybe_unused]] static inline int foo = 0;
};
```

I ask as I have a static data member whose type has a non trivial constructor that does useful stuff but is otherwise unused.

Comment: Interestingly enough, *"a variable"* could be of a static storage duration as well. Great question!

Comment: Is there a compiler that actually rejects/ignores the attribute on static data members? I assume `foo` qualifies as a variable.

Comment: I don't think the standard uses "variable" to include static data members as opposed to static duration variables. Not sure about what compilers do. My question was more about what the standard says they should do to be compliant. I know that the compiler should ignore attributes it does not recognize but I'm not sure about known attributes used in a non compliant way.

Answer (score 2):

[basic]/6 says that any object declaration constitutes a variable.  “non-static data member” appears in the list alongside “variable” because a non-static data member of *reference* type is not a variable.

Comment: So are you saying the standard regards a static data member as a "variable" and therefore the list in the standard  includes static data members as something to which [[maybe_unused]] can be applied.

Comment: @goneskiing: Yes, and I tried to explain the confusing presence of “non-static” in the list.

Comment: I ran into this issue using Resharper C++ in Visual Studio. The warning in resharper is tagged as [clang-diagnostic-ignored-attribute]. This implies to me that clang has an issue.

Comment: @goneskiing: I agree: Resharper is right that [Clang doesn’t like it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Qwt0agKqiZ5HPxvf), which seems like a Clang bug to me; GCC [accepts it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/egE6Xkv1dqryrywc) (but doesn’t issue the warning quite so easily anyway).